# How to display jquery date picker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to display JQuery ui datepicker calendar in a side bar and I would like the calendar to show all the time.
At the moment I only seem to be able to do that whenever a field receives focus or when the icon is clicked.

How can I get the calendar to appear in a sidebar block without waiting for a focus event and disappearing when a date is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `datepicker()` on a DIV instead of an input.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

From the jQuery UI site:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<div class="demo">
  Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean use a div instead of input field??? That sounds to simple and works perfectly...

Comment: yep - exactly!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

check out [inline mode](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline)